# Como altero tudo para um único valor php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

A minha pergunta é a seguinte:

Numa tabela, tenho uma coluna designada `nomecliente`.

Nessa tabela tenho vários registros, contudo a coluna `nomecliente` dos registros são diferentes uns dos outros.

Como poderia fazer um mysql_query `UPDATE`, para selecionar todos os registros da coluna e colocar um único valor a todos nessa mesma coluna?

Comment: vc quer deixar o nome do cliente igual para todos?

Comment: Exato, tudo com o mesmo nome.

Comment: negativaram a pergunta? :O

Comment: Essa pergunta está na fila de fechamento por supostamente não estar clara o suficiente. Para mim está bem clara, e se o rray (ou alguma outra pessoa) já não tivesse dado uma boa resposta, eu iria respondê-la prontamente. Assim sendo, vou marcar para "Deixar aberta".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para definir um valor para **todos os registros** de uma ou mais colunas apenas omita o `WHERE` no update. Alguns bancos de dados(como MySQL) tem uma 'trava' contra um update/delete sem `WHERE` pois geralmente isso é visto como um erro, na dúvida gera um backup da tabela para ter os dados antes da alteração.

```
UPDATE cliente SET nomecliente = 'sera mesmo'
```

Digamos a tabela tenha os seguintes registros

```
id|nome
1 |fulano
2 |ciclano
3 |beltrano
```

Depois dessa instrução `UPDATE cliente SET nome = 'mario'` a tabela ficará da seguinte forma:

```
id|nome
1 |mario
2 |mario
3 |mario
```

Comment: Dentro de 8 minutos já aceito a resposta.

Comment: Uma alternativa para esse bloqueio citado pelo @rray é usar `WHERE 1=1`